# how do I make this animation trigger on scroll over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4v2wK/

```
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
$({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
    duration: 3000,
     easing:'swing', // can be anything
     step: function() { // called on every step
         // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
         $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
     }
});

function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
}
```

Now I want to modify it so that it is only triggered when the user is scrolling by the div, not necessarily hovering over it, but the div is visible in his or her screen. Say this div is at the bottom of a long page, by the time the user gets there, the animation is over, and they miss the whole show.

Comment: you could use inview (https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) or write something your self. check for vieport size, change it on resize, and check scroll position and then you know if the element is in view

Comment: so you want the count down to start once the user reaches the target(div) ? or want the count down to start and ends as soon as user reaches the target ?

Comment: I would like it to start when they get there, the ending of it does not matter, but the beginning does.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this code will trigger you animation once it's 250px over the top of your div.

```
isScrolledIntoView();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    isScrolledIntoView(); 
});
function isScrolledIntoView(){
    $('.class').each(function(){   // add the class of the divs you want trigger on scroll over
        var $this = $(this).attr("id");  
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();

        if  ((elemTop >= docViewTop) && (((docViewBottom-250) >= elemTop))){
            // trigger your animation here
            // with $this as a selector
        }
    })
```